# How to add Endless Scrolling into my app Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

1.I added `gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.7'`

2.I specify the number per page of **gigs** from my 
**application_controller.rb** ,it lists all the gigs

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :initialize_user

  def initialize_user
    @gigs = Gig.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8)
  end 
end
```

Next to my views i do, **notice the last line**

```
<section class="body customtest">
  <div class="container gig-index">
    <div class="row experiment">
      <% @gigs.each do |gig| %>
      <div class="well for-h1-gig-second col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 ">
        <%= link_to (image_tag gig.image.url(:medium), :class=>"img-responsive"), gig %>
        <h1><%= link_to gig.title, gig %></h1>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= will_paginate @gigs %> # notice this line
</section>
```

Now everything works,i see the pagination "1,2,3 => next..."

So to apply the infinite scrolling I do in **app/assets/javascripts/application.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.pagination').length) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href');
      if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
        $('.pagination').text("Please Wait...");
        return $.getScript(url);
      }
    });
    return $(window).scroll();
  }
});
```

and create a file called index.js.erb for my Gigs controller in Gigs views,(though i have the code in **application controller**) and add in the code listed below.

```
$('#gigs').append('<%= escape_javascript render(@gigs) %>');
$('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript will_paginate(@gigs) %>');
```

Now i still see the "previews 1,2,3 next" thing,and when i scroll down it says "Please Wait..." , **but it never loads**.

Comment: Any javascript errors, or failed requests (network tab in Chrome's dev console)?

Comment: @Clark no nothing no errors,when i scroll down it just says  "Please Wait...",the error might be,because i have the code in application controller instead of the gig controller.But i do need it to be in application controller.

Comment: Do you at least see any request being sent/received when you try to scroll?

Comment: Started GET "/?page=2&_=1432236761545" for 109.76.185.196 at 2015-05-21 19:32:45 +0000                                                                                                                                
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as JS                                                                                                                                                                        
  Parameters: {"page"=>"2", "_"=>"1432236761545"}

Comment: Okay, that means you are sending the data that needs to be shown, just not showing it. You have an element with `id="gigs"` right? I only ask because I don't see it in your view excerpt.

Comment: Actually maybe not, what comes after that line? Something like `Rendered index.js.erb (1.0ms)` `Completed 200 OK in 6ms...etc`?

Comment: hmm for some reason it renders everything in the format you said,but not index.js.erb

Comment: What does it render? Based on `Processing by StaticPagesController#home` is it maybe `home.html.erb` or something like that? I think making `home.js.erb` would be the solution in that case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78469/discussion-between-mike-mccallen-and-clark).

Comment: @Clark please post your answer,so i can mark it as completed,i will fix it with some code,to be more exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with `$('#gigs').append('<%= escape_javascript render(@gigs) %>');`

1. You had no element with `id="gigs"`
2. You had no partial `_gigs.html.erb`

Adding those 2 things was all you needed.